# Visual Studio mark as error every property of class that inherit by ObservableObject

Tags: winui-3, community-toolkit-mvvm

I have two clsses that inherits by ObservableObject.
In the second class I use the first, but Visual Studio mark as error every his property as by attached image.
If I run the app, it work fine.

I use CommunityToolkit.Mvvm 8.1 version in a Winui3 app.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I guess this is related to this known [issue](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/issues/598).

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding Yes, it is it. but it is still unsolved

Comment: It seems to be an Intellicode issue on Visual Studio. We have to wait until they fix it. Meanwhile we can just ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is not a problem in the **CommunitToolkit.Mvvm** NuGet package. See [here](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/issues/598) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/67123).

The **CommunityToolkit.Mvvm** is working so you can just ignore these warnings for the moment until this get fixed.

As a temporary workaround, try using v8.0, restart Visual Studio and see if the warnings are gone.