# CommunityToolkit.Mvvm Source Generators are not working

Tags: c#, mvvm, winui-3, .net-7.0, windows-app-sdk

I have a Windows App SDK/WinUI 3 Packaged Desktop App project in VS 2022, targeting .Net7.
I installed the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm ver.8.1.0 NuGet package.
Can someone please tell me why am I getting these warnings? Also, you can see in the 2nd image that the source generators are not working.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFfug.png)

Here is my class that derives/inherits from ObservableObject
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxkiD.png)

I was expecting that Mvvm would work right out of the box.
I followed every tutorial and article I found on the internet.
Please enlighten me. Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry. The **CommunitToolkit.Mvvm** is working. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75611739/2411960).

Comment: Thanks @AndrewKeepCoding. Great YouTube channel by the way.